# Best way to create a multi-user/domain platform using Laravel as the framework

Tags: laravel

This is primarily a strategic question.

I have been using Laravel as of late to build some apps and have an multi-user platform/domain based.

In other words I want to create a web app (and ultimately a mobile app) that I can deploy as a new site/app for a new user who signs up.

So, for instance I have built a site all about Chihuahua's with features for dogs.

But I want to reproduce said site/app for a new user who will use the app to run a site about Dobermans.  Unique domain and everything, so I am thinking it would be a whole new install rather than sub-pages of the original app.

Does Laravel allow you to somehow create an app the way you want it and then deploy it out?  And then if you updated the base app you could re-deploy it similar to how wordpress works.

Comment: Downvoting a question without leaving feedback is a great way to improve a community. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bare bones laravel does not support multi domain and hosting. But it is possible to get some sort of api for a hosting service and domain service and have them deploy their "dog" site like that.